# Assign the average of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

Given the table below:

```
HomeID  | Device
a       | Mac1
b       | Win1
a       | Win2
c       | Android1
a       | Mac2
b       | Android2
d       | Win3
```

The goal is to find the home to device ratio. For instance, the ratio for `a` should be 1/3 since it has 3 devices pointing to it and `b` should be 1/2.

```
HomeID  | Avg
a       | 1/3
b       | 1/2
c       | 1
d       | 1
```

Comment: What **exactly** stops you from reaching your goal?

Comment: I am very new to SQL. I am trying stuff out but it doesn't seem to work. I want to learn.

Comment: show at least one thing you've tried that didn't work?  that's the best way to help us help you learn

Comment: Got it. So i shd post what i have tried. I will do that next time i ask a question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by the homeID, and then the ratio is the inverse of the count:

```sql
SELECT   HomeId, 1 / COUNT(*) AS avg
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY HomeId
```